# Paypal Pagos sin pasar por paypal

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

Actualmente en una web que tengo hay dos formas de pagar:

- Pago de productos:Cesta de productos -> paypal -> aceptar pago -> pagina de pedido pedido completado.
- Pago suscripción: Cesta con la suscripción -> paypal -> aceptar pago recurrente 30 dias -> pagina de pedido completado.

Pero ahora he visto, concretamente en just eat, que una vez pones tu cuenta de paypal te cobran directamente sin pasar por paypal.

Seria algo asi:

- Just eat carrito -> aceptar pedido -> fin

Sin pasar por paypal.

¿Alguien sabe decirme como lo esta haciendo?

Estoy usando la api de paypal desde una tienda creada en Laravel 5

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que buscas se llama **Adaptive Payments**, si lo usan algunas tiendas, lamentablemente solo está disponible para algunos socios, por lo que será casi imposible que lo integres.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht-ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/